# Some questions regarding Ramanujan summation -- Part I

Tags: analysis, divergent-series

The [Ramanujan Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) method, is a method through which divergent series can be summed to convergent values.

I have several questions regarding this summation method. For more info about the words used to describe divergent series summation methods, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) wiki article.

1. Is it a regular summation method?
2. Is it a linear summation method?
3. Is it a stable summation method?

More questions to come in Part II. Furthermore, I would like to point to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137530/ramanujan-summation) on MSE by Peter Tamaroff, which hasn't been answered yet. I am also curious as to what the answers to his question might be.